# Efficiency of OLS versus Quantile regression estimator

Tags: least-squares, quantile-regression, consistency, efficiency, least-absolute-deviations

If I have a linear model

$ y_i = x_i'\boldsymbol\beta + \epsilon_i $

and I assume that OLS estimator of $\boldsymbol\beta$ is **unbiased** and **consistent** and Least absolute deviation (LAD) estimator of $\boldsymbol\beta$ is also **consistent**, what are the conditions for LAD to be more efficient than OLS?

Does it depend on sample size? Under which assumptions (if any) about the error terms $\epsilon_i$ is OLS more efficient than LAD?